# Stop ArrayCollection from being constantly sorted (sort only once)

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

I've got a list propagated by an ArrayCollection that holds instances of a model class.
This model class has a class reference to a dictionary that holds stock values. Naturally these values get refreshed constantly.

When I apply my sort function to the ArrayCollection I do get the correct sorting, however the sort function constantly runs, I need it to run only once, though. So the sort should stop immediately after sorting the ArrayCollection for the first time.

My sort function is triggered on click of a header button (I'm working on a list based DataGrid optimized for mobile so constantly sorting the ArrayCollection is not only not required, it also requires too much performance) and looks like the following:

```
private function headerClick(event:MouseEvent):void {

    sField = event.currentTarget.id;        
    var sort:Sort = new Sort();
    sort.compareFunction = fidSort;

    (_list.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).sort = sort;
    (_list.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).refresh();
}

private function fidSort(a:Object, b:Object, fields:Array = null):int {

    if(a.fidList.fidMap[sField].fieldValue == b.fidList.fidMap[sField].fieldValue) {
        return 0;
    } else if(a.fidList.fidMap[sField].fieldValue > b.fidList.fidMap[sField].fieldValue) {
       return 1;
    } else{
       return -1;
    }
}
```

So, is there a way to stop the sorting process other than simply putting a boolean value at the end of the function to stop the sorting? That would mean that the function would still get dispatched with every update of the values, a rather undesired behavior.

Comment: Have you tried setting the array collection's sort property to null after the refresh executes?

Comment: Constant running of a function is an abnormal behavior. Isn't it ? Have you tried disabling the button after click. Might it be like, the button is pressed twice or thrice ?

Comment: @bedwyr, yes I tried that, didn't work though. Setting the sort to null followed by a refresh call sets removes the sort and sets the ArrayCollection back to it's default state. Without calling refresh() the sort will still work with every update.

Comment: @Vishwas Gagrani, that's not abnormal at all, rather than the default behavior of the way the sort has been implemented. Once the ArrayCollection gets updated, it will get sorted in case a sort is set.

Answer (score 2):

Al_Birdy is right, this is the default behavior of a `ListCollectionView` (which `ArrayCollection` extends).  `ListCollectionView` defines a method named `disableAutoUpdate()` which will prevent CollectionChange and PropertyChange events from being dispatched by the collection when items change.

This should then stop triggering your sort.  It's still not ideal, b/c the collection apparently keeps track of all the changes when you call this method, so it can replay them if you later call `enableAutoUpdate()`.

To work around this, you may just want to sort the data yourself, then create an `ArrayCollection` with the sorted data.

Comment: Unfortunately, `disableAutoUpdate()` prevents my `ArrayCollection` from being updated by the changing values of it's items as well. I guess sorting the data on my own would be a better way then, I'm just wondering if creating a new `ArrayCollection` is ideal. Wouldn't it be better to apply the sort directly to the `ArrayCollection(List)`'s source (which happens to be an `Array`)?

Comment: To answer myself, directly applying the sort on the ArrayCollection's source works, but takes forever, even on a i7 2600 machine. I used it like this: `(_list.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).source.sort(fidSort);`, to calling the very function I used before, just this time on the source `Array` directly.

Comment: @Al_Birdy sorting an Array should be just as fast or faster than sorting an ArrayCollection. Can you try doing the sort before the ArrayCollection is used as the dataProvider for the List? Doing the sort while the List is using the collection may be causing the List to do a lot of extra work. Ie. sorting this way may be generating a lot of CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE events (where the `kind` property is CollectionEventKind.RESET).

Comment: that's what I thought as well, which is why I find this result very odd. Unfortunately I need the sorting to be done at runtime as the user has to be able to sort the collection by a variety of parameters. However, I found that Christophe Herreman has implemented a very similar component (List based DataGrid) that already supports sorting. I'll have a look into it and report back once I looked into it.

Comment: I should have mentioned this earlier: maybe you can try calling `disableAutoUpdate()` before you do the sort, then after the sort call `enableAutoUpdte()`

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, had some other requirements with higher priorities to complete first. I'll try it asap!